# System control take over by whatsapp media playback or a call

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, audio

For some reason, as I activate media playback in WhatsApp or hold a call there, mobile phone controls are deactivated and the screen is blacked out until the playback, or the call ends.

This is a very unpleasant behaviour, how to deal with it? This happens also with a full charge; first I thought this would be some energy saving trick but it seems not.

**It is not even possible to regulate the audio volume during that.**

- On video playback this does not happen.
- I do not touch the proximity sensor on audio playback.

Device: Sony E6653. Androis OS 7.1.1, Kernel 3.10.84, build number 32.3.A.1.54

Comment: Are you covering your proximity sensor by any chance?

Comment: @ABochur do not think so. Good point! On whatsapp call, proper control of the proximity sensor would indeed make sense to swap the mode as held on ear or not.

Comment: @J.Doe does the screen do the same thing when you make a regular call not in WhatsApp?

Comment: @ABochur I can't tell as I have got a data only SIM for this device.

Comment: I suspect that it has to do with the proximity sensor even if you're not blocking it, something it's broken about it. Because both media and calls in WhatsApp will blacken your screen when close to your ear.

Comment: Go to Settings > About phone > Diagnostics > Test > Ear proximity. Does the phone vibration even when your hand/finger is not covering the proximity sensor?

Comment: this item is not available; if I search for it, it seems to be there but as I select it, it jumps to "About phone".

Comment: There's an app that lets you test your proximity sensor. When the sensor is covered, the app will show a hand over the sensor, when it's uncovered, the hand moves away. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zerosevengames.app.selfcheckProximity

Comment: @ABochur ah now that is interesting! indeed sth is wrong with the proximity sensor, you are right! the app shows it locked all the time, and if I bend on the corners very slightly, proximity is shown to go lower.
So given the sensor is fragged , what do I do now?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are describing, is a result of a faulty proximity sensor.

What's supposed to happen is, when you listen to voice note or make a call, the screen will stay on, but as soon as you put the phone to your ear, the screen turns off. When the sensor is broken, it thinks that the phone is always by your ear.

One way to get around this, is by using an app called [macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dmacrodroid&pcampaignid=APPU_1_vIuVWtTsHoKW5wKkt4mYBg).

You can set it in a way, that when the proximity sensor is activated while in WhatsApp, the screen will stay on.

Here are the few simple steps to set this up:

1. Open macrodroid  → *add makro  → sensors  → proximity sensor  → near  → ok*. Now press on proximity sensor and add each of the options separately.
2. Press on *actions* on the top of the screen  → *screen  → screen on/off  → screen on (alternative)  → ok*
3. Constraints  → device state  → application running  → running in foreground  → ok  → WhatsApp  → ok.  ↠ application running  → alive in background  → WhatsApp  → ok.
4. Now press on the check mark on the bottom, and give a name to this action.
5. From the main page of the app, press in macros, and after pressing on the one you just made, near constraints, press on *and* and change it to *or*. You should see the exact settings as I have below:

[image]

Now test this out. Go into WhatsApp and make a call. The screen will stay in during the call.

**Note:**

1. The screen will stay an as long as WhatsApp is running, and it will disregard the set sleep time. It will also stay on while not in WhatsApp, as long as WhatsApp is running in the background. If that happens, you can go into your recent apps, and swipe WhatsApp away.
2. I tested this in s galaxy s5. No guarantee that it works across all phones.

Comment: Upd - nice app but the maxro does not trigger. -.-

Comment: Does it all look like in the screenshot?

Comment: Make sure to enable the app from settings > accessibility

Comment: @J.Doe try this: macrodroid > macros > press on the macro you made, and press on the plus near *triggers* > applications > launched > WhatsApp > save

Comment: Worth checking by adding (or) alive in background since in both cases the foregoing app may be media player/ call +1// OP can try this and revert +1

Comment: If this works , OP would need to swipe Whatsapp from recents when not in use. OP can also check from settings > system logs if earlier macro was called when tested. If it was not called , then it supports what I said ( also to check from 3 dots menu in macro if logging is enabled)

Comment: @beeshyams thanks for your input. Edited. Waiting to hear from OP

Comment: Ok so: 1. I can be sure now if macro triggers by adding user log entry and a short buzz. 2. Macro does not trigger by proximity sensor activity, maybe because there is no event. 3. It triggers by launch of whatsapp, but it happens before I press playback. 4. Zrigger screen off does not trigger either.

Comment: @J.Doe it worked on my s5, so I'm not why it doesn't work by you. So I guess one thing I did help determine, is that your proximity sensor is broken, and there's why it's not working. Hope you have luck from here onwards